# dropDatabase() Error db does not exist but it Shows up on show dbs

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to drop a database from mongos shell but I get an error the database does not exist. But the database is listed in show dbs and I am able to switch to the database.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was able to delete the db from mongod shell. I still don't know why it didn't work. If mongos shell doesn't allow dropping db or since I had mongod shell open in another terminal that prevented mongos shell from dropping the db. Either way the error message is completely wrong.
[image]